# D3: how to rescale the pack layout to fit only visible circles?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I have a pack layout with multiple levels (depths), out of which a few first ones are made not visible (just like in the example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269:

[image]

... where the root node is hidden).

However, the scaling works by fitting ALL the circles in an svg container, not only the visible ones. This leads to lost space if a few top-cirles are made invisible...

What would be a good way to rescale the layout to fit only the visible circles in the container? I thought about checking all nodes for extreme x/y coordinates and rescaling based on that...

Comment: Did you happen to resolve this?